# Help with phrasing a survey question

Tags: style, structure

I think this sentence is awkwardly worded:  **Do(es) you/your company add job questions on job applications currently?**

I think it should say:  **Do you or your company currently add job questions on job applications?**

But I'm not sure since you would never say 'do your company currently..."

Comment: Laurie, welcome to Writers but I'm afraid this question is off-topic here. Please consider visiting the links in the on-hold box for more information about the site.

Answer (score 0):

It feels ambiguous. (I personally have trouble with the words 'add' and 'currently.')

It could be:

1. Do you, or does your company, include questions on applications, that are geared to assess applicants' qualifications (i.e. 'job questions')?
2. Do you, or does your company, include job questions on applications, which were not included in the past?

If it is a simple grammar question you are asking, I would state:

Do you, or does your company, currently include job questions on job applications?

Comment: Thank you, Thank you!  I'm not sure if this was the forum to post this question -- but your response was right on the mark!